# I dont understand why my d3js chart is not updating though it passes through update function

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, bar-chart, auto-update, dynamic-chart-series

The chart takes both revenue and profit data it updates for the first second and .remove().exit()
The function doesn't remove data 
Help me out.

Here is the [link for stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjkwht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fd3js%2Fd3js.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3Array from 'd3-array';
import * as d3Axis from 'd3-axis';
import * as d3Scale from 'd3-scale';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-d3js',
  templateUrl: './d3js.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./d3js.component.css']
})

export class D3jsComponent implements OnInit {
    private width: number;
    private height: number;
    private margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100};
    x: any;
    y: any;
    private svg: any;
    private g: any;
    private xaxisGroup: any;
    private yaxisGroup:any;
    value;
    flag = true ;
    ylabel;
    label;
    xlabel;
    bardata;
    starbucksData=[
    {
        "month": "January",
        "revenue": 23432,
        "profit": 8342
    },
    {
         "month": "February",
         "revenue": 19342,
         "profit": 50342
    },
    {
         "month": "March",
         "revenue": 17443,
         "profit": 35423
    },
    {
         "month": "April",
         "revenue": 26342,
         "profit": 18432
    },
    {
         "month": "May",
         "revenue": 34213,
         "profit": 29434
    },
    {
         "month": "June",
         "revenue": 50321,
         "profit": 45343
    },
    {
         "month": "July",
         "revenue": 54273,
         "profit": 47452
    }
]

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.initsvg();
    this.initdrawAxis();
    this.initAxis();
    this.axisLabel()
    // this.drawbars()
    this.d3update()
}

initsvg(){
    this.svg = d3.select('svg');
    this.width = +this.svg.attr('width') - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = +this.svg.attr('height') - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
    this.g = this.svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')'); 
}

//non repetable code.
initdrawAxis(){
    this.xaxisGroup=this.g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height +")")



this.yaxisGroup=this.g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
}

initAxis(){
    this.x = d3Scale.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, this.width]).padding(0.2);
    this.y = d3Scale.scaleLinear().rangeRound([this.height, 0]);
}

axisLabel(){
    this.ylabel =this.g.append("text")
        .attr("class","y axis-label")
        .attr("x", -(this.height/2))
        .attr("y", -60)
        .attr("font-size" , "20px")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")


    this.xlabel=this.g.append("text")
        .attr("class","x axis-label")
        .attr("x", 190)
        .attr("y", 330)
        .attr("font-size" , "20px")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("month"); 
}

drawbars(){
    this.bardata = this.g.selectAll('.bar')
        .data(this.starbucksData)
    this.bardata.exit().remove()
    console.log(this.bardata)
    this.bardata
        .attr('x',  (d) => this.x(d.month))
        .attr('y', (d) => this.y(d[this.value]))
        .attr('width', this.x.bandwidth)
        .attr('height', (d) => this.height - this.y(d[this.value]) )
        .attr('fill','blue')

    console.log(this.bardata)

    this.bardata
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr('x',  (d) => this.x(d.month))
        .attr('y', (d) => this.y(d[this.value]))
        .attr('width', this.x.bandwidth)
        .attr('height', (d) => this.height - this.y(d[this.value]) )
        .attr('fill','grey')

    console.log(this.bardata)

}

d3update(){
    d3.interval((d)=>{
        this.updatabledata()
        this.flag = !(this.flag)
        console.log(this.flag)
    }, 1000);

    this.updatabledata()

}

updatabledata(){
    this.value = this.flag ? "revenue" : "profit"
    console.log(this.value)

    this.x.domain(this.starbucksData.map(function(d){ return d.month }));
    this.y.domain([0, d3Array.max(this.starbucksData, (d) => d[this.value])]);
    var xAxisCall = d3.axisBottom(this.x)
    this.xaxisGroup.call(xAxisCall);
    var yAxisCall = d3.axisLeft(this.y)
        .tickFormat(function(d){ return "$" + d; })
    this.yaxisGroup.call(yAxisCall);
    this.drawbars()
    this.label = this.flag ? this.ylabel.text("profit") : this.ylabel.text("revenue")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your `drawbars()` function your missing a key step to add the class name `.bar` to your elements. That class name is used on the main `selectorAll('.bar')` so it can find the elements on re-rendering

the key line

```js
      .attr("class", "bar")
```

```js
  drawbars() {
    this.bardata = this.g.selectAll(".bar").data(this.starbucksData);

    this.bardata.exit().remove();

    this.bardata

      .attr("x", d => this.x(d.month))
      .attr("y", d => this.y(d[this.value]))
      .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth)
      .attr("height", d => this.height - this.y(d[this.value]))
      .attr("fill", "blue");
    console.log(this.value);

    this.bardata
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", d => this.x(d.month))
      .attr("y", d => this.y(d[this.value]))
      .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth)
      .attr("height", d => this.height - this.y(d[this.value]))
      .attr("fill", "grey");
  }
```

Comment: @VivekSumanthChintakula you're welcome! you can mark the post as solution if it worked for you,thks